# Mass chain handler in Vue2

Tags: vuejs2

I have a component (Vue2) with several buttons. After processing every button's @click, I need to call a method.

How can I do it without adding a call into each @click? Of course, all @clicks are different.

The only idea I see is to create component for the button, maybe there are better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Just use single handler for all `@click` events and pass the handler function for the specific button as an argument....

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    handleClick: function(handler) {
      handler()
      console.log("Common code executed")
    },
    button1: function() {
      console.log("Button 1 clicked")
    },
    button2: function() {
      console.log("Button 2 clicked")
    },
    button3: function(a) {
      console.log(`Button 3 clicked (with additional argument: "${a}")`)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.14/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="handleClick(button1)">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button" @click="handleClick(button2)">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button" @click="handleClick(() => button3('hi!'))">Button 3 (with additional argument)</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting idea, how did I manage to miss it?...